# Replace data frame values matching given condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data in a tab-separated file `test.tsv`.

```
Class   Length  Frag
I   100 True
I   200 True
P   300 False
I   400 False
P   500 True
P   600 True
N   700 True
```

I have loaded the data into a `pandas.DataFrame` object, and anywhere that Class = I and Frag = True I would like to set Class = F. [The following code](https://gist.github.com/standage/0d44652ff7b4406f3a14) does not seem to be working. What am I doing wrong, and what should I be doing?

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_table('test.tsv')
data.loc[(data.Class == 'I') & (data.Frag is True), 'Class'] = 'F'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your line

```
data.loc[(data.Class == 'I') & (data.Frag is True), 'Class'] = 'F'
```

you shouldn't use `is`.  `is` tests identity, not equality.  So when you're asking if `data.Frag is True`, it's comparing the Series object `data.Frag` and asking whether it's the same object as `True`, and that's not true.  Really you want to use `==`, so you get a Series result:

```
>>> data.Frag is True
False
>>> data.Frag == True
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
Name: Frag, dtype: bool
```

But since we're working with a series of bools anyway, the `== True` part doesn't add anything, and we can drop it:

```
>>> data.loc[(data.Class == 'I') & (data.Frag), 'Class'] = 'F'
>>> data
  Class  Length   Frag
0     F     100   True
1     F     200   True
2     P     300  False
3     I     400  False
4     P     500   True
5     P     600   True
6     N     700   True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `.apply()` with `axis=1` and a lambda expression for your condition/replacement . Example -

```
In [24]: df['Class'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'F' if x['Class'] == 'I' and x['Frag'] == True else x['Class'], axis=1)

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
  Class  Length   Frag
0     F     100   True
1     F     200   True
2     P     300  False
3     I     400  False
4     P     500   True
5     P     600   True
6     N     700   True
```